# The following sets of rules are mutually left-recursive in ANTLR

Tags: antlr4

The `expr` and `condition` gives me this error, it seems that antlr see it like a possible infinite recursion loop. How can i avoid it?

```
query : relationName '<-' expr;

relationName : identifier ;

identifier : (LETTER | IDENTIFIER1 | IDENTIFIER2)+;

expr : atomicExpr
       | selection
       | projection 
       | renaming
       | union
       | difference
       | product
       | naturalJoin;

atomicExpr : relationName | expr;

selection : 'select' (condition) atomicExpr;

condition : conjunction ('||' conjunction)*;

conjunction : comparison ('&&' comparison)*;

comparison : operand op operand | condition;
```

Answer (score 2):

The rule `expr` is indirect left recursive because it contains `atomicExpr` which also uses `expr` on the left hand side. However, `atomicExpr` is a pretty useless rule. By defining:

```
expr : relationName
       | selection
       | projection 
       | renaming
       | union
       | difference
       | product
       | naturalJoin;
selection : 'select' (condition) expr;
```

you will get exactly the same syntax, but without that recursion.

`condition` is a bit more difficult because the left recursion involves 3 rules (`condition` uses `conjunction` on the left hand side, which uses `comparison`, which uses `condition` again). You can resolve that by combining the separate rules into one:

```
condition:
    comparison
    | condition LOGICAL_AND condition
    | condition LOGICAL_OR condition
;
comparison: operand (op operand)?

LOGICAL_OR: '||';
LOGICAL_AND: '&&';
```

Precedence is ensured by the order of the alternatives. Later alts have a smaller precedence. And since this rule is recursive also on the right hand side, you don't need loops here.